# Insertion Sort algorithm java doubly linked list

Tags: java, sorting, insert, linked-list, insertion-sort

I have a doubly linked list with a sentinel node and I need to sort it using Insertion Sort with O(n^2) complexity. I have written this code but it does not work as it is supposed to.

Any help in general with insertion sort and specifically with a code?

```
    public void insertionSort()
    {
        int key,i;
        int size = getSize();
        this.restart();
        for(i = 2; i < size; i++)
        {
            this.next();  // Go to next node
            key = this.getVar(); // get the integer a node holds
            while(this.hasNext() == 1 && position.prev.var < key && position.var != -1)
            {
                position.prev.setNext(position.next);
                position.next.setPrev(position.prev);
                position.setNext(position.prev);
                position.setPrev(position.prev.prev);
                position.prev.setNext(position);
                position.next.setPrev(position);    
                this.goBack(); // go to the previous node
            }                       
        }

    }
```

Size is how many elements my list has. My sentinel has var = -1 so I want to stop when I am at the head that's why I use this.

```
position.var != -1
```

and `this.hasNext() == 1` is true as long as we are at a position != sentinel node .

In the specific example, I have 35 integers in my list:

> 5 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1

and I want to sort them this way:

> 9 5 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

UPDATE:
The code I use into the insertion sort is the following:

```
public int getSize()
        {
            int size = 0;
            this.restart();
            while(this.hasNext() == 1)
            {
                size++;
                this.next();
            }
            return size;
        }

public void restart()
        {
            position = header;
            previous = Sentinel;
        }

public void next()
        {
            previous = position;
            position = position.next;
        }

public int getVar()
        {
            return position.var;
        }

public void goBack()
        {
            position = previous;
            previous = previous.prev;
        }

    public int hasNext()
        {
            if(position.var != -1)
                return 1;
            else 
                return 0;
        }

    public void setNext(Node next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
```

public void setPrev(Node prev)
            {
                this.prev = prev;
            }

Also, I use a list iterator.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first number sequence is after you sorted it?

Comment: Nope it is unsorted as I add them to the list. And I need after I finish with the adding, to sort my list using insertion sort.

Comment: So what's the output after you sort them?

Comment: You'll need to post more source for someone to help. What do goBack(), getRequest(), and hasNext() actually do?

Comment: Btw, you never update `position` (or define it), so `position.var != -1` is always the same value, indicating it either doesn't sort at all, or never terminates (or maybe something in between).

Comment: mascoj I updated with some comments. About hasNext I write what it does.
Kennedy, after using my code I have this result:
5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Thank you. The 9 seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Yeap and I think that one of the mistakes is the thing that inside the while loop I go the previous nodes, and then in the next for loop I am not in the node I would like, but in the node I got after the while loop.

I mean, I use this.next() to go to the next node, but at the same time inside while loop I use this.goBack() to go to the previous nodes, which is a problem I think.

Comment: Do you have a `printlist` function so you can trace what happens? Or you could set a breakpoint and trace through it.

Comment: I have a printlist function that can print my list anytime I want. I am just totally stuck :(

Comment: We can't be sure the problem isn't somewhere else, or reproduce it without having the code for the functions you use, as they are non-standard. Often, people think the problem is somewhere it is not, which is why they find themselves stuck. So we better rule that out. Could you update the post with [the missing code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yeap I added the missing code that I use at my insertion sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the notes from my analysis of the inner loop, and you were right, there's definitely a problem there.

*position.unlink():*  step out of line, neighbours become direct neighbours

```
position.prev.next = position.next;  // TODO 1: position.next.prev = position.prev
position.next.prev = position.prev;  // TODO 2: position.prev.next = position.next
                  ^  Breaks TODO 1, but we can: position.prev.next.prev = position.prev
```

So we still need TODO 1 and then 2, in that order:

```
     -- TODO 1: position.prev.next.prev = position.prev
     -- TODO 2: position.prev.next      = position.next
```

*position.insertBefore(position.prev):* re-queue one place further back in line

```
position.next = position.prev;          // TODO 3: position.prev.prev = position
position.prev = a = position.prev.prev; // TODO 4: a.next = position
//           ^                          //   same: position.prev.next = position   
//           |                          // *Error 1!*
//           + breaks TODO's 1 and 2, *Error 2!*
//           + breaks TODO 3, but we can instead: position.next.prev = position
```

Regarding error 1, TODO 3 and TODO 4 both involve `position.prev`, setting both it's `next` and `prev` to `position`; this effectively surrounds `position.prev` 
with `position`. No matter if it steps forward or backward, it's direct neighbour will be `position`. After the one step though, everything is the same. Interesting structure - it's like the front and back door of your house both access the same spot.

*Error 2* makes it impossible to update `position.prev`, which is needed for *TODO*'s *1*, *2* and *3*. We can still meet *TODO 3* by using the alternate expression accessing `a.next` through `position.prev`'s `next` field, but *TODO's 1* and *2* can no longer be met.

*position.insertBefore(position.prev), continued:*

```
position.prev.next = position;        // DONE: 4 
position.next.prev = position;        // DONE: 3
```

These two lines complete TODO 3 and 4, so all that's left is:

```
     -- TODO 1: position.prev.next.prev = position.prev
     -- TODO 2: position.prev.next      = position.next
     -- TODO 5: fix Error 1
     -- TODO 6: fix Error 2
```

Fixing error 1 involves making sure TODO 1 and 2 are done before TODO 4, and fixing error 2 is making sure TODO 3 is done before `a` is assigned.

You end up with 8 assignments; in hindsight, not unsurprising for a doubly-linked list and a movement involving 4 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem:

```
        int j;
        // ...
        for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            this.restart();          // start at ith node
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
                this.next();
            key = this.getVar();     // same code as before
```

or use another variable that advances by one node at a time for each outer loop.

Also, shouldn't this.hasNext() be renamed to this.hasPrev() ?

The main part of the code seems correct, example diagram:

```
                // goal: swap B and C
                // initial state
          p        
    -> -> -> ->
    A  B  C  D
   <- <- <- <-
                // remove C from list
                position.prev.setNext(position.next);
                position.next.setPrev(position.prev);
          p
       ----->
    ->    -> ->
    A  B  C  D
   <- <- <-
         <----
                // update C next and previous                    
                position.setNext(position.prev);
                position.setPrev(position.prev.prev);
       p
    ----->
       -> -> ->
    A  C  B  D
   <- <-    <-
      <----
                // insert C into list
                position.prev.setNext(position);
                position.next.setPrev(position);
       p
    -> -> -> ->
    A  C  B  D
   <- <- <- <-
```